# How do i know if my server is refusing/timing out API calls?

Tags: linux, apache2

I have a relatively busy server (apache2) which serves api calls. The call volume varies greatly between day and night. Plus I believe there are some bursts of volume in between.
Recently I noticed the error for maxrequestworkers in my apache error log. I fixed it by increasing it and I dont notice that error anymore.

My question is:  **How do i know if my server is still refusing/timing out some API calls when the volume is very high.** Is there any log which shows the timed-out calls which it was unable to serve. Is it just the error log I should be keeping an eye on (which seems to be fine now).

My configuration is apache2 on ubuntu.

Also is there any log which logs the time taken to serve each API call.

Comment: look into your Apache Log, it tells you if he did not serve a 200

Comment: Are you referring to the error log or access log?

Comment: The Apache Logs are telling You, how many non 200 Requests are being happened, if you don't know where they are nor which one, I believe then this is the wrong site for yours ;)

Comment: Thanks. you are right. i am not a pro server admin so pardon my poor knowledge. But thank you for your answer. I could find the response served by apache in access log and it is a big relief to know that very few of api calls were not served 200

Comment: So, Your Decision is, either Let this Post look like a "Pro" (add all relevant information), and hide that you aren't _or_ move the Question to Superuser.com - ;)

Comment: Must be my karma. I can see questions here which go like "where-can-i-find-apache-error-log" & so on .. they get huge upvotes, lots of answers and no ridicule for poor knowledge/research. But I accept your verdict and will delete/move this to superuser

Comment: Questions seeking installation, configuration or diagnostic help must include the desired end state, the specific problem or error, sufficient information about the configuration and environment to reproduce it, and attempted solutions. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers and are unlikely to get good answers. - Once Times can be this asked one do not question 100 times the same, duplicating does not enhance it :) - however this is why I am “Pushing” you to update your question